# parse the xml by specifying the attribute names

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a xml from which I want to parse only specific attributes not all. I have 100s of attributes and the xml I provided is a sample with few attributes
. I want explicitly specify the attributes names and parse their values.
 Eg : I want to parse get the values of the Attribute names PersonN , VerifiedHuman
In my logic I want to parse the values by specifying attribute names like `<Name>PersonN</Name>` and parse its value
The result should be a csv.

```
<InterConnectResponse>
  <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  <ConsumerSubjects>
    <ConsumerSubject subjectIdentifier="Primary">
      <DataSourceResponses>
      <RiskViewProducts>
          <RiskViewAttribResponse>
          <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                  <Name>PersonN</Name>
                  <Value>3</Value>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute>
                  <Name>VerifiedHuman</Name>
                  <Value>2</Value>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute>
                  <Name>CurrAddrBlockIndex</Name>
                  <Value>0.61</Value>
                </Attribute>
           ------ Many More Attributes ---------
         </Attributes>
         </RiskViewAttribResponse>
     </RiskViewProducts>
     </DataSourceResponses>
    </ConsumerSubject>
  </ConsumerSubjects>
</InterConnectResponse>
```

Logic I am using : (I dont know how to specify the attribute names and get their values)In this code str3 is the above xml.

```
using (XmlReader read = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str3)))
{

    bool isValue = false;
    while (read.Read())
    {
        if (read.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && read.Name == "Value")
        {
            isValue = true;
        }

        if (read.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text && isValue)
        {
            output.Append((output.Length == 0 ? "" : ", ") + read.Value);
            isValue = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Expected output :

```
3, 2
```

Comment: Please note that what you're calling "attributes" aren't what are normally called attributes in XML. You may have no control over that, but it's worth at least being aware that it's confusing.

Comment: What do you want to do if there are multiple `ConsumerSubject` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to get all values in a dictionary.  Then you can extract only the ones you want.  Use xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication63
{
    class Program
    {
        const string XML_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string CSV_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XML_FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("Attribute")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("Name"), y => (string)y.Element("Value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(CSV_FILENAME);


            string[] attributesToRead = new[] { "CurrAddrTaxValue", "CurrAddrTaxMarketValue", "PrevAddrTaxValue" };
            //foreach (string attribute in attributesToRead)
            //{
            //    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", new string[] { attribute, dict[attribute] }));
            //}

            //all on one line

            string output = string.Join(",", attributesToRead.Select(x => dict[x]).ToArray());
            writer.WriteLine(output);

            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how do I get values from dictionary into a csv file ?

Comment: I really like this answer. 
But how do I get only values into the csv file for specific key ? and in my csv file I want only values in a single row separated by commas.
I am looking for some code like 
 
`var attributesToRead = new[] { "CurrAddrTaxValue", "CurrAddrTaxMarketValue", "PrevAddrTaxValue"};
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> row in dict.AsEnumerable())
                                {
                                    writer.Write(string.Join("," row.Value)) Where(row.key=> attributesToRead.Contains(ro);
                                }`
`Example output :  3 , 2 `

Comment: This gave me output like (in 3 separate lines) :

`CurrAddrTaxValue,3
CurrAddrTaxMarketValue,2
PrevAddrTaxValue,0`


But I am expecting like :

`3, 2, 0`  

I only want values and them in a single line. Sorry for being so specific.. I am trying to automate a huge process and this a part of it

Comment: Updated code one more time, but don't like it.  Not very robust and reading is very prone to errors.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group your attributes for example by product you could do the following.

```
var document = XDocument.Load(fileName); // or `= XDocument.Parse(xml);`
var attributesToRead = new[] {"PersonN", "VerifiedHuman"};
var productsElements = document.XPathSelectElements("InterConnectResponse/ConsumerSubjects/ConsumerSubject/DataSourceResponses/RiskViewProducts");
var products = productsElements.Select(product => new
{
    Attributes = product.XPathSelectElements("RiskViewAttribResponse/Attributes/Attribute").Select(attribute => new
    {
        Name = attribute.Element("Name")?.Value,
        Value = attribute.Element("Value")?.Value
    }).Where(attribute => attributesToRead.Contains(attribute.Name))
});
```

To get the desired output you can do this.

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
    foreach (var attribute in product.Attributes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(attribute.Value + ", ");
    }
}
```

To create an csv I recommend you use a library like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(@"C:\mypath\myfile.csv", FileMode.Append)))
{
    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in product.Attributes)
        {
            csv.WriteField(attribute.Value);
        }
        csv.NextRecord();
    }
}
```

Comment: This method will be parsing out all the attributes. I want to specify the attributes that I want to parse..

Comment: But this csv over writes if I parse couple of xmls.. how do I append data to it ?